# Calculating a cumulative sum with for loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, math, sum, cumsum

I'm trying to come up with a summation of variables within a model field of 27 layers. Most of the variables are applicable at each layer, but for one of the variables I'm gauging a change in height and therefore subtracting the previous layers "top height" from the total height at the given layer.

Basically, I'm just not sure how to represent a cumulative sum at any point using for loops.

I'm currently trying, per my code, to use two for loops to do the cumulative sum and getting the error.

```
"Attempted to access flheight(299,162,0,12); index must be a positive integer or logical."
```

I know that is because "flheight(299,162,0,12)" doesn't exist because there is no "layer = 0" for the third dimension.

```
no2molcm2 = 0;
dh = 0;
patm = 0;
no2ppm = 0;
for n=0:26
    for i=1:27
        T = Temp(299,162,i,12); % K 
        dh = (flheight(299,162,i,12)*100) -flheight(299,162,n,12)*100;
        patm = sum(Pres(299,162,i,12))*(1/101325); %atm
        R = 82.06; % cm3*atm/(k*mol)
        av = 6.022140857747*(10^23); % 1/mol
        no2ppm =  sum(no2(299,162,i,12));
        no2molcm2 = cumsum(((no2ppm*av*patm)/(R*T))*dh);
    end
end
```

My question here is how on earth can I tell matlab that when it sees this input (or the error output) to just set this equal to zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, per a comment I realized I should just take the easy way and specify the first layer manually then sum the remaining ones. Here is the code that fixed it:

```
latco = 1;
lonco = 200;
layer1 = (no2(latco,lonco,1,12)*av*(Pres(latco,lonco,1,12)* 
   (1/101325)))/(R*Temp(latco,lonco,1,12)*h1);
        for n=1:26
        for i=2:27
                T = Temp(latco,lonco,i,12); % K 
                dh1 = flheight(latco,lonco,i,12)*100;
                dh2 = flheight(latco,lonco,n,12)*100;
                dh = dh1 - dh2;
                patm = sum(Pres(latco,lonco,i,12))*(1/101325); %atm
                no2ppm =  no2(latco,lonco,i,12);
                no2molcm2_26 = sum(((no2ppm*av*patm)/(R*T))*dh);
            end
        end

no2final = layer1 + no2molcm2_26
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a try-catch structure might be the simplest and most straightforward quickfix to what you asked.

```
try
    "something that can go wrong"
catch ME
    "what to do if it didn't work"
end
```

Note that if you know the reason to the error, the best practice is to check if the reason will be applicable . i.e. `if(i==0) (do what you must)`. Otherwise, unexpected error cases are simply suppressed.

Comment: A bit like taking a cannon to fire on a mosquito. Effective, but quite overkill.